# Passing CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData() to HTTPPost gives error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, http-post

I am reading the HTML from the CKEditor and am able to display it in the alert but for some odd reason when I get to the ajax post it gives an error. I have identified this by removing it and passing a plain string just in case. That works fine.

```
function GetHTML() {
    var _content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
    alert(content);
    var _filename = $("#pages").val();

    var url = "/CMS/UpdateHTML/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {content: _content, filename: _filename },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

I never actually get to the controller code. It just gives an error

> error : [object Object]

the code in the controller is

```
<HttpPost()>
Function UpdateHTML(content As String, filename As String) As ActionResult
        stop

        Return Json("")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem it seems that if you place the attribute in the code it works.

```
<ValidateInput(False)>
```

I saw this in an article [Using CKEditor with Razor for .NET MVC 3](http://peterkeating.co.uk/using-ckeditor-with-razor-for-net-mvc3/)

In the article it is mentioned how this is very important else an error will be generated.

> "[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Form value was detected from the client..." exception is
>   thrown because there is HTML being sent to the server. The
>   [ValidateInput(false)] attribute will prevent this error happening,
>   however we are opening ourselves up to a security vulnerability.